# Difference between bsearch and find in ruby

Tags: ruby, bsearch

I'm trying to match files from a directory to other files in an other directory, and its sub directories using ruby.

I tried to make a small test using this file architecture:

```
tree .
.
├── src
│   ├── lol
│   │   └── toto
│   └── lolilolpouet
│       └── tutu
│           └── tata
├── test
│   ├── tata
│   └── toto
└── test.rb
```

My ruby code is:

```
require 'find'

src_dir_files = []
Find.find('./src') do |file|
  src_dir_files << file
  puts "found #{file}"
end


Dir.foreach('./test') do |file|
  next if file == '.' or file == '..'
  puts "search for /#{file}"
  res = src_dir_files.bsearch{|s| s.end_with? "/#{file}"}
  puts "Found :#{res}"
end
```

The output is:

```
found ./src
found ./src/lol
found ./src/lol/toto
found ./src/lolilolpouet
found ./src/lolilolpouet/tutu
found ./src/lolilolpouet/tutu/tata
search for /tata
Found :./src/lolilolpouet/tutu/tata
search for /toto
Found :
```

The search for toto returns no result.
Any idea why, and how to fix it ?

Edit: the code above behave as intended if I replace bsearch by find.
Can any one explain to me the difference between theses two methods ?

I uploaded a tgz if you want to try it:

http://cl.ly/331J0C2e2D0Y

Comment: you seem to have changed the question from what it was originally

Answer (score 1):

I would do as below:

```
src = Dir["./src/**/*"] 
#=> ["./src/lol", "./src/lol/toto", "./src/lolilolpouet", "./src/lolilolpouet/tutu", "./src/lolilolpouet/tutu/tata"]
Dir["./test/**/*"].each do |test_file|
  file = src.find { |x| x.include? test_file.gsub(/.*\//, "") }
  puts "Found #{file}"
end

# >> Found ./src/lolilolpouet/tutu/tata
# >> Found ./src/lol/toto
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but... Any idea why mine doesn't work as intended ? Did I misunderstood something in the use of bsearch ?

Comment: @Antzi I tried `bsearch` too and for whatever reason did not work, I am not sure I fully understand how `bsearch` should work, and it had behaved funny when I tried using it in the past, so I would suggest using find, and if you are so keen about "search performance" then I would advice you write your own binary search implementation

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `src_dir_files` isn't sorted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian: I disagree. The input data not being sorted is pretty much the only reason why `bsearch` would fail.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorting `src_dir_files` does not seem to help with `bsearch`

Comment: @bjhaid: The array needs to be sorted *with respect to the block*, i.e. it needs to be sorted such that the block returns `false` for any element left of the target and `true` for any element right of the target or the target itself. IOW: the array needs to be sorted such that all filenames that end with `'toto'` (in the second example) are at the end of the array.

Comment: Then bsearch is is useless here, I suggest you include this explanation in your answer